Dynamic Links Creation - Missing the Get Started button in Console
I'm trying to create a Dynamic Link via Console, but there doesn't seem to be a "Get Started" button, so I can't figure out how to get to the page where I can create them. Has anyone encountered this?
enter image description here
I tried to manually add /links/ or /creation/ to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/awesome-project/durablelinks, but it keeps redirecting me back to the start page, beyond which I can't i can pass.
I also checked Hosting, made sure there were both default domains and one of my custom ones that was verified.

It is currently not possible to enable Firebase Dynamic Links for a new Firebase project if it did not already have this feature enabled before the sunset announcement on August 25, 2023.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you don’t see the “Get Started” button on the Firebase Dynamic Links dashboard, it is likely because API WEB KEY is missing.
To resolve this:

Navigate to your Firebase project settings by clicking the gear icon in the top left and selecting “Project Settings”.
In the “General” tab, look for the API WEB KEY. If it’s not visible, you need to enable an authentication method first.
Go to the “Authentication” section in the left-hand menu and enable the Email/Password sign-in method.
After enabling this, return to the “General” tab in “Project Settings.” You should now see the API WEB KEY.
Once the API WEB KEY is visible, the “Get Started” button should appear in the Firebase Dynamic Links console.

This should solve the issue.

Enable Firebase Authentication First then it will start showing "Continue Anyway" button as Dynamic Links is no longer supported, and will stop working on August 25, 2025.

